# Вывести дату в DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

jQuery UI Datepicker

Знатоки, как при выборе даты записать её в переменную и после выполнить какое нибудь действие, например в консоль вывести её же ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство [`onSelect`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) для назначения обработчика выбора даты

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(d, i){
           console.log(d);
        }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
 
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```